# Firestore security rules can't retrieve request.auth.token.name

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Firebase security rules dose not recognize request.auth.token.name

I want to apply security rules using user's display name.
I used signInAnonymously and updateProfile.

This is my Client code

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app')
require('firebase/auth')
require('firebase/firestore')

firebase.initializeApp(~~~)
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(({user}) => {
  user.updateProfile({
    displayName: 'ABC',
  }).then(() => {
    // {..., uid: '~~~', displayName: 'ABC', photoURL: null}
    console.log(user.toJSON()) 

    var db = firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('HelloCollection').doc('WorldDoc').get()
      .then((doc) => { console.log('Success') })
      .then((err) => { console.log('Failed', err) })
  })
})
```

This is my Firestore security rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /HelloCollection/{docId} {
      // allow read, create, update: if true; // This evaluated true.
      // This evaluated false.
      allow read, create, update: if request.auth.token.name == "ABC";
    }
  }
}
```

I expected 'Success', 
but actual output is

```
Failed FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (webpack-internal:///3120:352:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (webpack-internal:///3120:14802:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (webpack-internal:///3120:15293:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (webpack-internal:///3120:11280:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///3120:11209:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///3120:11249:28)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///3120:1630:20)
    at run (webpack-internal:///1421:66:22)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///1421:79:30)
    at MutationObserver.flush (webpack-internal:///358:18:9)
```

Comment: shoudn't `request.auth.token.name` be `request.auth.token.displayName` ?

Comment: @Dadboz
request.auth.token.name is right way to retrieve requester's displayName
[firebase API doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request)

Comment: Since displayName is a custom field which you're setting in the token, you cannot access it via name. So try the solution mentioned by @Dadboz above.

Comment: Did you solve this, I'm also stuck with it?

Comment: Does anyone solve this probem? I'm also stuck...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't directly solved this problem but I bypassed the problem by making it authencate by UserID instead of User name as follows:

```
request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.token.sub
```

Please note that your query making HelloCollection should also be changed so as to store user id with texts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example..

```
match /stuff/{candy} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.token.name == candy
}
```

@fre bern is right. You can access user's display name by "request.auth.token.name" .. if u cant get it to work.. mb sth else is wrong with your code